# Strange error with simple struct

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
struct Adjacent_signs
{
    char signs[] =  { '+','-','*','/' };
};
```

I'm trying to compile it with newest intel's compiler and I'm getting following error:
**error : assertion failed at: "shared/cfe/edgcpfe/decl_inits.c", line 2034**
So I went there and found:

```
    //
// TEMPLATE CLASS vector<bool, Alloc> AND FRIENDS
//
typedef unsigned int _Vbase;    // word type for vector<bool> representation
const int _VBITS = 8 * sizeof (_Vbase); // at least CHAR_BITS bits per word
```

What I'm curious is:
What on earth is wrong with my code and why I'm getting assertion failure for totally unrelated vector type?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you have a file, say `test.cpp`, which contains exactly the 4 lines you posted? It should not compile because of the missing semicolon at the end of the struct definition.

Comment: Can you supply an MCVE?

Comment: This sounds like a compiler bug; reporting some handled condition.

Comment: @user3344003 If he's getting an assertion failure from the compiler, it's clearly a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry about the missing semicolon. That semicolon is in my code, I've must have missed it when I was copying it in here.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, MCVE is in OP ;)

Comment: I haven't been able to compile it with any compiler available to me.  The consensus seems to be that the array size cannot be determined.  gcc, clang, and visual studio 2013 all fail unless the size is specified like `char signs[4]`.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando can you confirm that you are getting that error message *during compilation*?

Comment: @DrewDormann yep, I can confirm that.

Comment: gcc 4.8: "error: too many initializers for 'char[0]'"

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's surely is a bug in those compilers, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I'm not a language lawyer, but surely if 4 compilers reject your code it's more likely your code is broken than all 4 compilers.

Comment: I'd say there is a bug with their diagnostic system, but that isn't anything new for ICC (for me anyways).